# No setter/field 'image' found on class 'model'

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I already find question-related to my problem but I still don't really get the idea. I want to get data images from the database URL in firebase storage using glide. but my logcat shows this line.

```
2023-02-14 10:02:36.417 25063-25063/com.isjieman.ocion W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for post_image found on class com.isjieman.ocion.model.Post
2023-02-14 10:02:36.436 25063-25063/com.isjieman.ocion W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for background_image found on class com.isjieman.ocion.model.User
2023-02-14 10:02:36.436 25063-25063/com.isjieman.ocion W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for profile_image found on class com.isjieman.ocion.model.User
2023-02-14 10:02:36.438 25063-25063/com.isjieman.ocion W/Glide: Load failed for  with size [960x240]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
```

the problem is only for field image on the model. i already succeed on retrieve the other data from firebase except the image only. how do i solve this more technically? glad if someone wants to explain my problem

here's the database structure

```
{
  "Posts": {
    "-NNsor5WiX9wxTDf7qo5": {
      "category": "Art",
      "description": "tes 123",
      "duration": "-",
      "paymentMethods": "e-wallet",
      "postId": "-NNsor5WiX9wxTDf7qo5",
      "post_image": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/final-project-idn.appspot.com/o/Posts%20Pictures%2F1675990621049.jpg?alt=media&token=f7b747c0-1efe-4f43-9ff1-729c7d99c7c1",
      "priceRange": "Rp 0 - 10.000",
      "publisher": "6FzpJ2sQC9gewbUIGHB8hiNWK1z2",
      "title": "tes"
    }
  },
  "User": {
    "6FzpJ2sQC9gewbUIGHB8hiNWK1z2": {
      "background_image": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/final-project-idn.appspot.com/o/Default%20Images%2Fimg_background.png?alt=media&token=b51e7cf5-2015-4cc4-9583-159373d081e2",
      "bio": "Member of NCT",
      "email": "mark@gmail.com",
      "link": "",
      "profile_image": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/final-project-idn.appspot.com/o/Profile%20Pictures%2F6FzpJ2sQC9gewbUIGHB8hiNWK1z2.jpg?alt=media&token=d174fad9-2f8c-4964-83ec-549f18876587",
      "uid": "6FzpJ2sQC9gewbUIGHB8hiNWK1z2",
      "userName": "marklee"
    }
  }
}
```

here's my User model

```
class User {
    private var uid: String = "0"
    private var userName: String = ""
    private var email: String = ""
    private var bio: String? = null
    private var link: String? = null
    private var profile_image: String = ""
    private var background_image: String = ""

    constructor()

    constructor(uid : String, userName : String, email : String, bio : String, link : String, profile_image : String, background_image : String){
        this.uid = uid
        this.userName = userName
        this.email = email
        this.bio = bio
        this.link = link
        this.profile_image = profile_image
        this.background_image = background_image
    }

    //function UID
    fun getUID(): String{
        return uid
    }

    fun setUID(uid: String){
        this.uid = uid
    }

    //function User Name
    fun getUserName(): String{
        return userName
    }

    fun setUserName(userName: String){
        this.userName = userName
    }

    //function Email
    fun getEmail(): String{
        return email
    }

    fun setEmail(email: String){
        this.email = email
    }

    //function bio
    fun getBio(): String?{
        return bio
    }

    fun setBio(bio: String?){
        this.bio = bio
    }

    //function link
    fun getLink(): String?{
        return link
    }

    fun setLink(link: String?){
        this.link = link
    }

    //function Profile Image
    fun getProfileImage(): String{
        return profile_image
    }

    fun setProfileImage(profile_image: String){
        this.profile_image = profile_image
    }

    //function Background Image
    fun getBackgroundImage(): String{
        return background_image
    }

    fun setBackgroundImage(background_image: String){
        this.background_image = background_image
    }

}
```

here's Post model

```
class Post {
    private var postId: String = ""
    private var title: String = ""
    private var post_image: String = ""
    private var description: String = ""
    private var category: String = ""
    private var priceRange: String = ""
    private var duration: String = ""
    private var paymentMethods: String = ""
    private var publisher: String = ""

    constructor()
    constructor(
        postId: String,
        title: String,
        post_image: String,
        description: String,
        category: String,
        priceRange: String,
        duration: String,
        paymentMethods: String,
        publisher: String
    ) {
        this.postId = postId
        this.title = title
        this.post_image = post_image
        this.description = description
        this.category = category
        this.priceRange = priceRange
        this.duration = duration
        this.paymentMethods = paymentMethods
        this.publisher = publisher
    }

    //Get
    fun getPostId(): String{
        return postId
    }

    fun getTitle(): String{
        return title
    }

    fun getPostImage(): String{
        return post_image
    }

    fun getDescription(): String{
        return description
    }

    fun getCategory(): String{
        return category
    }

    fun getPriceRange(): String{
        return priceRange
    }

    fun getDuration(): String{
        return duration
    }

    fun getPaymentMethods(): String{
        return paymentMethods
    }

    fun getPublisher(): String{
        return publisher
    }

    //Set
    fun setPostId(postId: String){
        this.postId = postId
    }

    fun setTitle(title: String){
        this.title = title
    }

    fun setPostImage(post_image: String){
        this.post_image = post_image
    }

    fun setDescription(description: String){
        this.description = description
    }

    fun setCategory(category: String){
        this.category = category
    }

    fun setPriceRange(priceRange: String){
        this.priceRange = priceRange
    }

    fun setDuration(duration: String){
        this.duration = duration
    }

    fun setPaymentMethods(paymentMethods: String){
        this.paymentMethods = paymentMethods
    }

    fun setPublisher(publisher: String){
        this.publisher = publisher
    }

}
```

here's my PostAdapter.kt

```
class PostAdapter(private val mContext: Context,
                  private val mPost: List<Post>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.ViewHolder>()
{
    private var firebaseUser: FirebaseUser? = null

    inner class ViewHolder(@NonNull itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        var profileImage: CircleImageView
        var tvUsername: TextView
        var likeButton: ImageButton
        var tvTitle: TextView
        var tvPrice: TextView
        var tvDescription: TextView
        var tvSeeMore: TextView
        var postImage: ImageView

        init {
            profileImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cvProfile)
            tvUsername = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCvUsername)
            likeButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cvFav)
            tvTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCvTitle)
            tvPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCvPrice)
            tvDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCvDesc)
            tvSeeMore = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCvSeeMore)
            postImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivPostImage)

        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_timeline, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        val post = mPost[position]

        Glide.with(mContext.applicationContext).load(post.getPostImage()).into(holder.postImage)
        holder.tvTitle.text = post.getTitle()
        holder.tvDescription.text = post.getDescription()
        holder.tvPrice.text = post.getPriceRange()

        publisherInfo(holder.profileImage, holder.tvUsername, post.getPublisher())
    }

    private fun publisherInfo(
        profileImage: CircleImageView,
        tvUsername: TextView,
        publisher: String
    ) {
        val usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("User").child(publisher)

        usersRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists())
                {
                    val user = snapshot.getValue(User::class.java)

                    Glide.with(mContext.applicationContext).load(user!!.getProfileImage()).into(profileImage)
                    tvUsername.text = user!!.getUserName()
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, error.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }

        })
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mPost.size
    }
}
```

any help i would really appreciate. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the following warning:

```
No setter/field for post_image found on class com.isjieman.ocion.model.Post
```

Because in the `Post` class, you have an incorrect getter for the `post_image` field. The getter is defined as:

```
fun getPostImage(): String{
    return post_image
}
```

While it should be defined as:

```
fun getPost_image(): String{
    return post_image
}
```

You're getting the following warnings:

```
No setter/field for background_image found on class com.isjieman.ocion.model.User
No setter/field for profile_image found on class com.isjieman.ocion.model.User
```

Due to the exact same reason as above. You have these getters:

```
fun getBackgroundImage(): String{
    return background_image
}

fun getProfileImage(): String{
    return profile_image
}
```

Which should have been defined as:

```
fun getBackground_image(): String{
    return background_image
}

fun getProfile_image(): String{
    return profile_image
}
```

Bear in mind that Firebase Realtime Database serializes/deserializes any public fields and public properties that follow JavaBean naming conventions for getters and setters. That's the reason why you got those warnings.